# Why Is My Jest Function Mock Affecting Another Test

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have the test cases :

```
import { loginPagePresenter } from './LoginPagePresenter'
import { apiGateway } from 'config/gatewayConfig'
import { authRepository } from './AuthRepository'

it('should update the auth repository user with the token, email and set authenticated observable when successesful api call', async () => {
  const authenticatedStub = {
    'success': true,
    'message': 'successful login',
    'email': 'a@b.com',
    'token': '123'
  }

  apiGateway.post = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(authenticatedStub)

  loginPagePresenter.email = 'a@b.com'
  loginPagePresenter.password = 'aaabbbcom'
  await loginPagePresenter.submit()
  expect(authRepository.user.token).toBe('123')
  expect(authRepository.user.email).toBe('a@b.com')
  expect(authRepository.authenticated).toBe(true)
})

it('should not update the user model when NOT successesful api call', async () => {

  const notAutenticatedStub = {
    'success': false,
    'message': 'bad login',
    'email': '',
    'token': ''
  }

  apiGateway.post = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(notAutenticatedStub)

  loginPagePresenter.email = 'a@b.com'
  loginPagePresenter.password = 'aaabbbcom'
  await loginPagePresenter.submit()
  expect(authRepository.user.token).toBe(null)
  expect(authRepository.user.email).toBe(null)
  expect(authRepository.authenticated).toEqual(false)
})
```

The first test is affecting the second test. In other words if I comment out the first test then the second test works. I have checked the production code **it works** fine. But the mocking function of the first is having a side effect on the second (it looks like I can't reset the returned resolved function).

Can somebody explain how to fix this?

Comment: What line does it fail on?  The way you are mocking `apiGateway.post` looks fine, are you clearing out your `authRepository` values after the bad login?

Comment: Ah ha! Good sire I think you have a point. The problem is how do I clear it? We are not using a dependency injection container so how would I clear down a class that is imported in typescript using 'import { authRepository } from './AuthRepository'' ?

Comment: I solved the problem by using `spyOn` and `mockImplementation` (or whatever function you need) and then `jest.restoreAllMocks()` after each test.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add a `jest.clearAllMocks()` on your test file inside a `beforeEach()` like:

```
import { loginPagePresenter } from './LoginPagePresenter'
import { apiGateway } from 'config/gatewayConfig'
import { authRepository } from './AuthRepository'

beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
});

it('should update the auth repository user ...', async () => {
  ...
})

it('should not update the user model when NOT ...', async () => {
  ...
})
```

That will clear all mocks before each test runs.

Or you can also clear each individual mock with `mockFn.mockClear()`

Read more about it here: [jest.clearAllMocks()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestclearallmocks) and [mockFn.mockClear()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockclear)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but this does not work. I believe the issue may be tied to the fact that I am using a class in a 'static' like way. I'd rather not mock the entire class. But I have added the actual file which is being mocked.

Comment: @Exitos Did you solve your problem ?